# Do we have more than one $D$ term for a single gauge group?

Tags: supersymmetry

I'm reading this [note](http://people.sissa.it/~bertmat/teaching.htm) in chapter 6 which discusses $ {\cal N} = 2 $ supermultiplets, though the discussion is quite general and applies to $ {\cal N} = 1 $ fields in the adjoint representation. I summarize the discussion given in the paper here with a slightly simplified situation and notation for clarity. Suppose we have some field, $ \Phi $, in the adjoint representation of a gauge group $SU(N)$. The Kahler term for the field is

\begin{equation}\int d ^2 \theta \Phi ^\dagger e ^{ 2 g V ^a T ^a} \Phi =g D ^a \phi ^\dagger T ^a \phi + ...\end{equation}

and the kinetic gauge term gives,

\begin{equation}W^\alpha _a W_\alpha^a=\frac{1}{2} D ^a D ^a+...\end{equation}

The paper then goes on to integrate out the $D^a$ fields which gives,

\begin{equation}D^a =\Phi ^\dagger T ^a \Phi\end{equation}

Then the authors go on to introduce more ${\cal N} =1$ field, $H$. The $H$ field Lagrangian takes the form,

\begin{align}{\cal L} &= \int d^4\theta H ^\dagger e^{2q V ^a t ^a} H+ \int d^2\theta W^\alpha _a W_\alpha^a + ...\\&= g D ^a \Phi ^\dagger T ^a \Phi + \frac{1}{2}D_aD_a...\end{align}

where $t_a$ are the generators in the representation of the $H$ fields.

So far I have no issues, however then do something strange. They go on to again integrate out the $D$ fields, but they do so independently of the fields introduced earlier in the adjoint representation. However, don't we have a single $\vec{D}$ field for every gauge group, not every representation? So how come we are able to consider the sectors independently of one another?

Comment: I posted this question here, http://www.physicsoverflow.org/17846/can-you-have-more-than-one-%24d%24-term-for-each-gauge-group, as well but as it has not yet received an answer and I need one as soon as possible I reposted it here. I hope that is okay.

Comment: I am inclined to agree with you. I am not a SUSY expert but it seems like the D term should have both the contributions from 6.3 and 6.6. Eqn 2.2.1 in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.2684v2.pdf seems to agree with this.

Comment: @DJBunk: I see, thanks for your input (and the useful reference). Maybe they were just being sloppy but I've seen similar results in other papers so I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you have a link to another reference that does something similar?

Comment: In http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9603042 see eqn 2.5 and the discussion below. It seems as though the cross terms cancel (although I don't see why myself) so while the D term should strictly have both pieces in it, the cross term in $D^2$ cancels.

Comment: @DJBunk: Thanks for the link. I think (and this is through the help of the response on the crosspost, your reponse, and the links you provided) that there will not be any cross terms in a single $D$ term. However, as far as I can see there will still be inevitable cross-terms in $D^2$. So you can integrate out the fields seperately if you wish but when calculating the potential you have to be careful to include all the terms. In other words in this case you need, $(\Phi^\dagger T^a \Phi + H^\dagger t^a H)^2$.